# How to open new tab in Firefox with Shift+click

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the behavior of my firefox shortcut on the Windows 7 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/439881/can-i-change-the-behavior-of-my-firefox-shortcut-on-the-windows-7-taskbar)

How to adjust Firefox for opening new tab (NOT new window) with Shift+LeftMouseClick on link in current tab?

I know that Ctrl+click made such thing, or MiddleMouseButton click, but I need exactly Shift+LeftMouseClick, because I just did this Shift+click for million times in Opera and this combination is now a reflex.

Any plugins or settings or advises how to made such adjustment?

Comment: You should rather get used to the correct shortcut...

Comment: This is the last option. When you work with something so long that this is become reflex - it is very hard to revert the process because it became subconsciousness.

Comment: @ThiefMaster if you use FF then I think my answer will help you for your future reference :)

Comment: Why is **this** question, asked in 2011, marked as duplicate of another one, that asked later, in 2012? Shouldn't it be vice versa?

Answer (score 6):

Actually i would like to comment [@avirk's answer](https://superuser.com/a/408398/113441), but, i don't know why, i can't comment any answer to this question.

@avirk's answer helped me to completely solve the issue, so I give him the bounty, but i have to change some details, and so, I want to summarize all the actions that does the trick for me, for the future readers.

- Оpen page `about:config`, and change the value of variable `browser.tabs.loadInBackground` to **`false`**;
- Install [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) addon;
- Open Tab Mix Plus settings;
- Go to `Links` tab and set the option `Enable Single Window Mode`
- Go to `Events` tab, `Tab opening` sub-tab, and in the group `Focus/Select tabs that open from` set the option `Links`.
- At the same tab and sub-tab, in the group `Inverse Middle-click or Control-click focus of:` set the option `Links`.

Now, the problem is solved: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> opens link in the new tab and moves focus to new tab, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> opens link in the background tab. Exactly like Opera does, which is needed.

Comment: FYI, you cannot [comment freely](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment) at the moment because you have a rep score of less that 50. Unfortunately, the system doesn't warn you that you can lose privileges by dishing out a bounty (if it moves you below a certain score threshold).

Comment: The downside being that you cannot have several Firefox windows open any more.

Comment: Yep. But I never need that, so, personally for me it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

First of all download [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) addon for the Firefox. After installing it you will find it under the `Tools` menu with the name of Tab Mix Plus Options. After launching the addon now see the `Links` tab and check/tick the option `Enable single window mode`.

Now under the `Events` tab select the `Tab opening` option and check/tick the option Middle-click or Control-click opens items in current tab. Now it will disable the control of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open new tab and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> will open the new tab.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) Firefox add-on has in the Links tab the option of "Enable Single Window Mode".

This option will force Shift-Click to open in a new tab rather than in a new window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Tab Utilities](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/) Will let you do that
From their page:

> 15.Mouse clicking options, including Left/Middle/Right/Double/Ctrl/Alt/Shift-click on bookmarks/links/tabs/tab bar/New Tab button

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was closest to my target - this this the only addon from mentioned above that allows to customise mouse click settings. Unfortunately, it allows only two options on Shift+LeftMouseClick: default and open in the same tab. So it can't help to solve my task

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/08/15/change-firefox-keyboard-shortcuts-add-on-extension/

It contains the direct link to the extension so open it from Firefox itself.

Hope it helps :) but be careful, you might pass the reflex through your genes ;)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this addon contains only keyboard shortcut settings, I didn't find mouse click settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a help page by Mozilla concerning keyboard shortcuts:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts.
It includes a recommendation for this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/
Seems to be the most 'official' version to me.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this addon contains only keyboard shortcut settings, I didn't find mouse click settings.

Comment: You're right, sorry for not testing careful enough.

Answer (score 0):

Following shows how to customize shortcuts using addon "customizable-shortcuts"
http://www.techairlines.com/2011/09/24/custom-firefox-keyboard-shortcuts/
 ,And this is link for addon
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this addon contains only keyboard shortcut settings, I didn't find mouse click settings.