# Can I change the behavior of my firefox shortcut on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I have to admit that I've developed a nasty habit.  When I want a new browser window, I <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the Firefox icon to make a new window of Firefox.  Lately, though, I've been really wanting to get in the habit of just creating a new tab instead of creating a new window.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can change what the keyboard shortcut actually does, e.g. can I have it start Firefox with some sort of shortcut that would prompt it to start a new tab rather than a whole new window?

Comment: or just `cntl-T` for a new tab

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate. This one asks for a way to open a new tab when Shift-Clicking the FF icon on the taskbar; the other asks for a way to open a new tab when Shift-Clicking a link on a page. The accepted solution works for both though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have need to download the [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) add-on for Firefox.

[image]

After installing it you will find it under the `Tools` menu with the name of `Tab Mix Plus Options`. After launching the addon now see the Links tab and check/tick the option **Enable single window mode**.

Now under the **Events** tab select the Tab opening option and check/tick the option Middle-click or Control-click opens items in current tab. Now it will disable the control of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open new tab and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> will open the new tab.

If you want to focus on the  new tab immediately then go to **Events** tab, `Tab opening` sub-tab, and in the group `Focus/Select tabs that open from` set the option `Links`.

Comment: Thank you avirk, this was the most feature-rich solution to my immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I follow the question but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> inside of a Firefox window will open a new tab. Firefox support has a full list of [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs).

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension this should allow you to change the shortcuts for the key bindings.